# Why decompression of long string (EXIF) from watermarked image (with successful compression) gives error?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, gzip, sharpziplib

## Problems Background

I'm currently working on a **Universal Windows Platform** application in C# using Visual Studio 2015. 
In the project, I'm using **SharpZipLib.Portable** to perform compression and decompression for a long string (get from **EXIF**) before embed the information into the image.

After that, I will retrieve the bits back from the LSB value of each pixel (8 bits) of image and do decompression to get the EXIF back. The process is as below:

> String➡compression➡bits array of compression➡embed into image➡get back the     bits array➡decompression➡original string

I'm testing using images with 440*440 and 256*256 dimension.
My problem now is that when I do decompression, I cannot get the original string back and the decompression gives error:

For 440*440 image:

```
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.SharpZipBaseException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Unexpected EOF
  Source=ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Portable
  StackTrace:
       at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams.InflaterInputStream.Fill()
       at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams.InflaterInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
       at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
       at RenderImage.Services.GZipCompression.Decompress(Byte[] bytes)
       at RenderImage.Services.Watermarking.Extracting(Byte[] pixelData, Int32 stringByteLength)
       at RenderImage.ReadInfoFromImage.<Extract_Click>d__1.MoveNext()
  InnerException:
```

For 256*256 image:

```
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=GZIP crc sum mismatch, theirs "-1895135477" and ours "-1621298539
  Source=ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Portable
  StackTrace:
       at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipInputStream.ReadFooter()
       at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
       at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
       at RenderImage.Services.GZipCompression.Decompress(Byte[] bytes)
       at RenderImage.Services.Watermarking.Extracting(Byte[] pixelData, Int32 stringByteLength)
       at RenderImage.ReadInfoFromImage.<Extract_Click>d__1.MoveNext()
  InnerException:
```

## Programme Code

### Compression and Decompression

```
namespace RenderImage.Services
{
    class GZipCompression
    {
        public static byte[] Compress(string text)
        {
            if (text == null)
                return null;

            using (Stream memOutput = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipOutputStream zipOut = new GZipOutputStream(memOutput))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(zipOut))
                    {
                        writer.Write(text);

                        writer.Flush();
                        zipOut.Finish();

                        byte[] bytes = new byte[memOutput.Length];
                        memOutput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        memOutput.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                        return bytes;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Decompress(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes == null)
                return null;

            using (Stream memInput = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            using (GZipInputStream zipInput = new GZipInputStream(memInput))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zipInput))
            {
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Watermarking

```
namespace RenderImage.Services
{
    class Watermarking
    {
        public static byte[] Embedding(byte[] pixelData, byte[]     compressedString)
        {
            byte[] embedded = new byte[compressedString.Length * 8];
            string[] binary = compressedString.Select(bytes => Convert.ToString(bytes, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < compressedString.Length; i++)
            {
                int[] b = binary[i].Select(chars => Convert.ToInt32(chars)).ToArray();
                int jump = i*8;
                embedded[jump] = (b[0] == 49) ? (byte)1 : (byte)254; 
                embedded[jump+1] = (b[1] == 49) ? (byte)1 : (byte)254;
                embedded[jump+2] = (b[2] == 49) ? (byte)1 : (byte)254;
                embedded[jump+3] = (b[3] == 49) ? (byte)1 : (byte)254;
                embedded[jump+4] = (b[4] == 49) ? (byte)1 : (byte)254;
                embedded[jump+5] = (b[5] == 49) ? (byte)1 : (byte)254;
                embedded[jump+6] = (b[6] == 49) ? (byte)1 : (byte)254;
                embedded[jump+7] = (b[7] == 49) ? (byte)1 : (byte)254;
            }

            for (int counter = 0; counter < embedded.Length; counter++)
            {
                if (embedded[counter]==(byte)254)
                {
                    pixelData[counter] &= embedded[counter];
                }
                else
                {
                    pixelData[counter] |= embedded[counter];
                }
            }
            return pixelData;
        }

        public static string Extracting(byte[] pixelData, int stringByteLength) //read until the last byte in the pixel data that contain the last bit of long string
        {
            byte[] extracted = new byte[stringByteLength]; //string array of the info that make up of 8 bits
            byte embeddedBit = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < stringByteLength; i++)
            {
                int jump = i * 8;
                extracted[i] = pixelData[jump];
                extracted[i] <<= 1;
                extracted[i] |= (byte)(pixelData[jump + 1] & embeddedBit);
                extracted[i] <<= 1;
                extracted[i] |= (byte)(pixelData[jump + 2] & embeddedBit);
                extracted[i] <<= 1;
                extracted[i] |= (byte)(pixelData[jump + 3] & embeddedBit);
                extracted[i] <<= 1;
                extracted[i] |= (byte)(pixelData[jump + 4] & embeddedBit);
                extracted[i] <<= 1;
                extracted[i] |= (byte)(pixelData[jump + 5] & embeddedBit);
                extracted[i] <<= 1;
                extracted[i] |= (byte)(pixelData[jump + 6] & embeddedBit);
                extracted[i] <<= 1;
                extracted[i] |= (byte)(pixelData[jump + 7] & embeddedBit);
            }

            var decompressString = GZipCompression.Decompress(extracted);
            return decompressString;
        }
    }
}
```

The string that I want to embed:

```
string patientInfo = "$ exiv2 -pt img_1771.jpg "+
                        "\nExif.Image.Make Ascii       6  Canon"+
                        "\nExif.Image.Model Ascii      20  Canon PowerShot S40"+
                        "\nExif.Image.Orientation Short       1  top, left"+
                        "\nExif.Image.XResolution Rational    1  180"+
                        "\nExif.Image.YResolution Rational    1  180"+
                        "\nExif.Image.ResolutionUnit Short       1  inch"+
                        "\nExif.Image.DateTime Ascii      20  2003:12:14 12:01:44"+
                        "\nExif.Image.YCbCrPositioning Short       1  Centered"+
                        "\nExif.Image.ExifTag Long        1  196"+
                        "\nExif.Photo.ExposureTime Rational    1  1 / 500 s"+
                        "\nExif.Photo.FNumber Rational    1  F4.9" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.ExifVersion Undefined   4  2.20" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal Ascii      20  2003:12:14 12:01:44" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.DateTimeDigitized Ascii      20  2003:12:14 12:01:44" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.ComponentsConfiguration Undefined   4  YCbCr" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.CompressedBitsPerPixel Rational    1  5" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.ShutterSpeedValue SRational   1  1 / 501 s" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.ApertureValue Rational    1  F5" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.ExposureBiasValue SRational   1  0 EV" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.MaxApertureValue Rational    1  F2.8" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.MeteringMode Short       1  Center weighted average" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.Flash Short       1  No, auto" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.FocalLength Rational    1  21.3 mm" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.MakerNote Undefined 450(Binary value suppressed)" +
                        "\nExif.MakerNote.Offset Long        1  942" +
                        "\nExif.MakerNote.ByteOrder Ascii       3  II" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.Macro Short       1  Off" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.Selftimer Short       1  Off" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.Quality Short       1  Superfine" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.FlashMode Short       1  Auto" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.DriveMode Short       1  Single / timer" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.FocusMode Short       1  Single" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.ImageSize Short       1  Large" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.EasyMode Short       1  Manual" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.DigitalZoom Short       1  None" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.Contrast Short       1  Normal" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.Saturation Short       1  Normal" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.Sharpness Short       1  Normal" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.ISOSpeed Short       1  100" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.MeteringMode Short       1  Center weighted" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.FocusType Short       1  Auto" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.AFPoint Short       1  Center" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.ExposureProgram Short       1  Program(P)" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.LensType Short       1(65535)" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.Lens Short       3  7.1 - 21.3 mm" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.MaxAperture Short       1  F5" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.MinAperture Short       1  F8" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.FlashActivity Short       1  Did not fire" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.FlashDetails Short       1" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.FocusContinuous Short       1  Single" + 
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.AESetting Short       1  Normal AE" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.ImageStabilization Short       1(65535)"+
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.DisplayAperture Short       1  49" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.ZoomSourceWidth Short       1  2272" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.ZoomTargetWidth Short       1  2272" +
                        "\nExif.CanonCs.SpotMeteringMode Short       1  AF Point" +
                        "\nExif.Canon.FocalLength Short       4  21.3 mm" + 
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.ISOSpeed Short       1  100" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.MeasuredEV Short       1  13.63" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.TargetAperture Short       1  F5" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.TargetShutterSpeed Short       1  1 / 501 s" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.WhiteBalance Short       1  Auto" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.Sequence Short       1  0" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.AFPointUsed Short       1  3 focus points; center used" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.FlashBias Short       1  0 EV" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.SubjectDistance Short       1  782" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.ApertureValue Short       1  F5" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.ShutterSpeedValue Short       1  1 / 523 s" +
                        "\nExif.CanonSi.MeasuredEV2 Short       1 - 6.00" +
                        "\nExif.Canon.ImageType Ascii      32  IMG: PowerShot S40 JPEG" +
                        "\nExif.Canon.FirmwareVersion Ascii      24  Firmware Version 1.10" +
                        "\nExif.Canon.FileNumber Long        1  117 - 1771" +
                        "\nExif.Canon.OwnerName Ascii      32  Andreas Huggel" +
                        "\nExif.Canon.ModelID Long        1  PowerShot S40" +
                        "\nExif.Canon.CameraInfo Short      21  42 3 32769 378 32769 0 0 0 259 2 0 10 0 0 0 57 198 5 0 0 0" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.UserComment Undefined 264(Binary value suppressed)" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.FlashpixVersion Undefined   4  1.00" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.ColorSpace Short       1  sRGB" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.PixelXDimension Short       1  2272" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.PixelYDimension Short       1  1704" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.InteroperabilityTag Long        1  1416" +
                        "\nExif.Iop.InteroperabilityIndex Ascii       4  R98" +
                        "\nExif.Iop.InteroperabilityVersion Undefined   4  1.00" +
                        "\nExif.Iop.RelatedImageWidth Short       1  2272" +
                        "\nExif.Iop.RelatedImageLength Short       1  1704" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.FocalPlaneXResolution Rational    1  8114.29" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.FocalPlaneYResolution Rational    1  8114.29" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.FocalPlaneResolutionUnit Short       1  inch" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.SensingMethod Short       1  One - chip color area" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.FileSource Undefined   1  Digital still camera" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.CustomRendered Short       1  Normal process" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.ExposureMode Short       1  Auto" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.WhiteBalance Short       1  Auto" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.DigitalZoomRatio Rational    1  1.0" +
                        "\nExif.Photo.SceneCaptureType Short       1  Standard" +
                        "\nExif.Thumbnail.Compression Short       1  JPEG(old - style)" +
                        "\nExif.Thumbnail.XResolution Rational    1  180" +
                        "\nExif.Thumbnail.YResolution Rational    1  180" +
                        "\nExif.Thumbnail.ResolutionUnit Short       1  inch"+
                        "\nExif.Thumbnail.JPEGInterchangeFormat Long        1  2036" +
                        "\nExif.Thumbnail.JPEGInterchangeFormatLength Long        1  5448";
```

Comment: It will be very hard to help you without the relevant piece of code <hint>.

Comment: So, what is the question? Where your code goes wrong? Maybe at line x? Yes, that is probably the error. We can try to find x if you show us the code..

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough information to reproduce the problem but if I had to guess I'd blame this line:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zipInput))
```

`zipInput` is a `Stream`; an unbounded stream of arbitrary bytes. The `StreamReader` constructor without an encoding parameter assumes a stream of UTF8 bytes and I bet that's not what a `GZipInputStream` is. UTF8 [enforces rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences) and if you don't follow the rules you get an exception.

So what should you do? That depends on what you pass to `Decompress`, what encoding it is in, and what you do with the result; and you haven't shown us any of those things. Find out the encoding of whatever is passed to `Decompress` and use that, or just use `zipInput.Read` and return the decompressed bytes, don't assume it is UTF8.